# How to identify vertical text with yob/pdf-reader?

Tags: ruby, pdf-reader

I have some code which uses the yob/pdf-reader gem to fetch the text from a PDF file and search for certain strings in it. Recently I got the issue that vertical text may interfere with my logic to identify text that belongs to the same line.

My question is: Does someone know a way to distinguish text orientation with pdf-reader?

Comment: I recently use pdf reader, but all I did is to use Regex to play with text. Can you share a bit of code here, or a GitHub link ?

Comment: What is your goal? I use pdf-reader in a similar way to parse e.g. receiver information from letters. For this purpose I wrote custom classes for some internal things like PageTextReceiver which expose the parsed text runs. As I am only interested in text in certain areas I wrote analyzing logic which filters and examines exactly that.

Comment: @jonsa It gives me lots of pain. So if I could see, your code, may be helpful for me... :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I summarized my findings and experiments in a blog post: http://blog.peschla.net/2014/04/parsing-pdf-text-with-coordinates-in-ruby/

Comment: Awesome... I liked it. If I have problem with *pdf-reader*, I will contact you.. Agreed ? :-)

Comment: Sure, if I can help. And if you find out how to identify vertical text, remember my question here ;)

Comment: @jonas.. sure.. I am very new to pdf-reader.. I am still reading and palying with the gem. But your blog will help me a lot..